# Access environment variables in production build Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript, production-environment

I want to deploy a production build of angular app with a configurable API URL for the user to test it out. I use the environment.ts but after the production build, I do not know how to configure the variables.

What approach needs to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Angular-CLI? It should be easy, then. You have something like this:

```
src/
  app/
  environment/
    environment.ts
    environment.prod.ts
```

Simply put different url in `environment.prod.ts` and your prod build gets a second url. E.g. let's say your `environment.ts` looks like this:

```
{
  "production": false,
  "apiUrl": "http://localhost:8080"
}
```

Put this in `environment.prod.ts`:

```
{
  "production": true,
  "apiUrl": "https://example.com/api"
}
```

You can setup more environments, check that section of `.angular-cli.json` and angular-cli repo.

**Edit:** As per your comment, you want more.

> Yes but still this is not configurable after the build isn't it? Because I don't know what url the user want to use therefore I want to make it configurable from the outside after deploying the build.

Let's continue this scenario further. Let's have a backend client:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { apiUrl } from '../environment/environment.ts';
@Injectable()
export class BackendService {
    backendUrl: string = apiUrl;      

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

    get(endpoint: string, params: any): Observable<any> {
      const url= `${this.backendUrl}/${endpoint}`;
      return this.httpClient.get(url, params);
    }
}
```

Simplified, but works. By default, you set your own URL. But your components can set the url on the fly, and get other things from that url.

Now, the next step would be, offering which backends you have. This can be a preconfigured array, or you can let the client enter the url freely (simply input box). You can have a component that does that, and configures this service here. You should probably also have a separate service for your "proper" backend, where, e.g. your auth lies. But this all really depends on your scenario.

Comment: Yes but still this is not configurable after the build isn't it? Because I don't know what url the user want to use therefore I want to make it configurable from the outside after deploying the build.

Answer (score 11):

The environment*.ts file contain build time configurations, which you cannot change after the build. If you need to change your configuration after the build, you need to put them in a different place and retrieve them dynamically when the application starts

What you can do is:

**Step #1**: put your json configuration files under src/assets/config/[envName].json.

Note: it has to be json format, not ts format

**Step #2**: Add a new config service

```
import {Inject, Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Rx';
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";

/**
 * Declaration of config class
 */
export class AppConfig
{
//Your properties here
  readonly production: boolean;
  readonly name: string;

  readonly apiBaseUrl: string;

}

/**
 * Global variable containing actual config to use. Initialised via ajax call
 */
export let APP_CONFIG: AppConfig;

/**
 * Service in charge of dynamically initialising configuration
 */
@Injectable()
export class AppConfigService
{

  constructor(private http: HttpClient)
  {
  }

  public load()
  {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let confName = environment.name + '.json';
      this.http.get('/assets/config/' + confName).map(res => res as any).catch((error: any): any => {
        reject(true);
        return Observable.throw('Server error');
      }).subscribe((envResponse :any) => {
        let t = new AppConfig();
        //Modify envResponse here if needed (e.g. to ajust parameters for https,...)
        APP_CONFIG = Object.assign(t, envResponse);
        resolve(true);
      });

    });
  }
}
```

**Step #3**: In your main module, add this before declaring the module

```
/**
* Exported function so that it works with AOT
* @param {AppConfigService} configService
* @returns {Function}
*/
export function loadConfigService(configService: AppConfigService): Function 

{
  return () => { return configService.load() }; 
}
```

**Step #4**: Modify the module providers to add this
    providers: [
      …

```
  AppConfigService,
  { provide: APP_INITIALIZER, useFactory: loadConfigService , deps: [AppConfigService], multi: true },


],
```

**Step 5**: In your code, instead of using environment.configXXX, use this

```
import {APP_CONFIG} from "../services/app-config.service";

//…
return APP_CONFIG.configXXX;
```

This is a simplified example, you'll actually need to make some changes if you use angular universal as you need to have absolute urls when making an http call

Comment: A Typescript file would have to compiled during build time. If the file is JSON the OP could change the configuration after this point.

Comment: I am not getting what you are pointing at, our code is compiled by angular compiler to produce js, before executing

Comment: when you put ts in assets folder, it is not compiled, its working fine for me, and it saves the extra code of route resolver, that you have to write above, to be able to access the json file

Comment: Hi David, do you have a simple plunker demo perhaps?

Comment: @OreoFanatics no I don't. But I've listed the steps clearly so maybe try it and post if you've got any error. That's the pattern I use on all my angular projects

Comment: But How custom config.json without especific build by environment?

Comment: But How custom config.json without especific build by environment? 

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      let confName = environment.name + '.json';
....

This way you need to build your app with specific environment (dev,hml,beta,prd)

Answer (score 5):

- Put your configurations in a ts file, in assets folder
- just like you are fetching environment.ts, fetch that file and use its configurations
- Contents of assets folder is not minimized, thus they can be configured in production build as well

Comment: did this solved your question, or you have anything to ask?

Comment: what's not working I have my code this way only, can you specify, or share screen at my skype id : learnakshayjain

Comment: I changed the url but my build still read the old one (the one was there during the build)

Comment: for this, you need to stop the compiler using ctrl + c, then restart it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161797/discussion-between-akshay-vijay-jain-and-oreofanatics).

Comment: @Akshay Vijay Jain:sir once above procedure is done....we have upload only config file in the server instead of whole build am i correct?

Answer (score 2):

### Do we really need APP_INITIALIZER to load dynamic environment variables

Well unless we need some async call to get them. Otherwise I would suggest this:

***env.js***

```
(function (window) {
  window._env = window._env || {};
  window._env.url= 'http://api-url.com';
}());
```

***index.html***

```
<head>
  <script src="env.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
```

Finally add it in ***angular.json***

```
"assets": [
              "any/env.js",
```

Now you can just read the window using a service in your app