# is there any way to configure global url after taking build in angular4 with cli

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular-cli

I have different environments and have a different rest-API configuration.Is it possible to configure the URL after taking the build.

Now I have set into
environment.ts for development

```
export const environment = {
url:''// development
}
```

environment.prod.ts for production:

```
 export const environment = {
    url:''// prod
    }
```

**problem:**

After taking the build and hosted on the server and needs to configure with different service URL: Don't want to take the build again.

Example:
I have hosted the application in IIS and I can able to change the web configuration in production.

Comment: I think that the short answer is you can't.

Comment: You can't use Angular CLI's environment files for runtime configuration - you'll have to pull the runtime config via HTTPClient.

Comment: See here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938035/access-environment-variables-in-production-build-angular-4/47938411#47938411