# Angular - modify environment in app.component.ts and prevent further loading

Tags: angular

I have attempted to containerize my Angular 4 application.  The logic is that, when the Docker container starts, it first executes a python script which creates a config.json file in the assets directory, and populates the key/value pairs with values that are read from the container's environment variables.  Then, the webserver actually starts.

My AppComponent loads this config.json file, and replaces values in environment with that of the file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { OAuthService } from 'angular-oauth2-oidc';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'ncmt-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'NCMT';

  constructor(
    private oAuthService: OAuthService,
    private http: Http) { 

      this.http.get('assets/config.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise()
      .then((config) => {
        if (config.issuer !== "default") {
          environment.issuer = config.issuer;
          console.log("Setting Issuer to " + config.issuer);
        }

        if (config.apiBaseUrl !== "default") {
          environment.apiBaseUrl = config.apiBaseUrl;
          console.log("Setting API Base Url to " + config.apiBaseUrl);
        }

        if (config.clientVersion !== "0.0.0") {
          environment.clientVersion = config.clientVersion;
          console.log("Setting Client version to " + config.clientVersion);
        }

        environment.user_info_endpoint = environment.issuer + "/connect/userinfo";
        console.log("Environment settings:");
        console.log(environment);
        this.loadDiscoveryDocument();
      }).catch(reason => this.loadDiscoveryDocument());
  }
```

The problem I am running into is that some of the components are already trying to do things like pull data from the API, before AppComponent has gotten a change to pull config.json and actually change the environment variables.

Is there a way to prevent the application from loading any additional components until the work with config.json is done?

Comment: You could put your whole app under a top level empty route that has a resolver.

Comment: Try using APP_INITIALIZER injection tokens. See here if  you can some of the code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938035/access-environment-variables-in-production-build-angular-4/47938411#47938411

Comment: @David That is the correct answer, and what APP_INITIALIZER is commonly used for apparently, after doing some research.  If you post an answer, I will accept.

Comment: If @David doesn't answer, could you blgrnboy. It would give the answer more visibility

Comment: @ahong I did not post an answer as it'd be the same one as the other question I alread answered