# Angular 5 How to load global variables from assets

Tags: javascript, angular

In my angular 5 application I need to load some global variables like principal Url and some other stuff, I am following this example:
[github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3855#issuecomment-301864970)

So with this GET call in app.component:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/config.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .toPromise()
      .then((config) => {
        // do stuff with the config
        console.log(config)
      });
  }
```

I can load all my variables, but now I am not sure that all the variables are loaded before I need them around the application.

Are there a way to achieve this, or some other way to load global variables?
And is a good practice to create a file: `global.ts` to store all my variables providing it around my app?

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794

Comment: If you want to source settings from a ts file, it means that it'll be included in the build. Meaning you have to do separate builds for each environments. That's basically what the environment.[name].ts files are for in angular cli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having set of global variables is never a good idea but... it strongly depends on case of your project. When we are talking about using global variables you and your coworkers need to be one hundred percent sure what you are doing - for example make sure that your variable will not mutate state by someone else because application could crash. Here you have wiki - why global variables are bad idea [Global Variables Are Bad - C2 Wiki](http://wiki.c2.com/?GlobalVariablesAreBad)

Let's come back to your angular case:
You can easly create new typescript file where you will have your global variables. Remember to decorate your file with `{ Injectable } from '@angular/core';` than you have to import them to point where your application starts `import { GlobalAssets } from './globalAssets '`. Register source in providers  `providers: [GlobalAssets ]`. After all you can reference GlobalAssets in your components by IoC.

It can cause some problems and it is always better to register and read your necessary files ( configurations and other globals, like fetching necessary data from other endpoint ) before bootstraping application [Reading data before application startup in Angular](https://gist.github.com/fernandohu/122e88c3bcd210bbe41c608c36306db9) - not hundred percent sure how it was changed in Angular 5.

Comment: I understand the wiki but is too generic, I need some settings in my global file, it can't be another place, so I'm following the `Reading data before startup` and it seems to work

Comment: If we are talking about global configuration files it is always better to read them once before application starts to make sure that everything is in place before components or services will load. You can have for example production/development ip addresses for endpoints. After all when you want to switch you just changing one bool flag in config.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there a way to achieve this, or some other way to load global
>   variables? And is a good practice to create a file: global.ts to store
>   all my variables providing it around my app?

Yes it is !
Create a file called globals.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class Globals {
  anyVariable: string = 'test';
}
```

Then just access it by importing it in your current component.

```
import { Globals } from './globals'
```

Don't forget to add the dependency injection in your app module like this

```
providers: [Globals]
```

You can access Globals entity from any point of your App via Angular dependency injection.

Comment: Is it posible to import my variable into a .js file?