# Angular production release package - where is environment.prod.ts values

Tags: angular

I have executed this command: ng build --prod --environment=prod to create the production release package. This creates a package in dist folder.

Where is the values of environment.prod.ts? Somehow, can I modify these property values. If this is possible, then I can use the same QA package and just by modifying this environment specific properties, I can create the production package.

In another way, for a java application, we will create the war and put all environment specific properties outside of war. Is something like this is possible in Angular?

Comment: The values are bundled up and minified into one of the .js files (i think it's `main.bundle.js`)

Comment: Ya I could see it in main.bundle.js. Is there a way to externalize this? That way, we can use the same QA package for Prod also just by changing the env specific prop fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can only do that by creating another script and including that directly in index.html; you will include a different script for QA and for prod.

Pay attention though that would be a custom implementation, outside of the regular angular tooling.

Answer (score 0):

The environment.prod's content is baked into the build, you cannot change the values easily. I've seen some people doing string replacements in the bundled js file, but I would not recommend it.

What you could do instead if retrieve dynamically at runtime the configuration for your environment, which would be located in the assets folder as json files. Json files will remain untouched by the build process, meaning you can mofigy them after the build if needed.

Basically, you need to use  APP_INITIALIZER to load the config before the app starts.

Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794