# Support multiple environments in the same build angular 2

Tags: angular, rest, build, development-environment, production-environment

I am working on an angular 2 application with Rest services. We are building one war file to run the application. There are two environments on which it needs to run - "dev" and "prod". The requirement is that the application should support these environment in same build. 
So I cannot use - ng serve --environement=prod
I have tried the way shown in the link - http://tattoocoder.com/angular-cli-using-the-environment-option/
But here again I have to manually provide the environement name. Is there any way in angular 2 to read the environment name from a server file.

Comment: Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794

Comment: It's still reading the environment name from a file emvironment.ts , not from the server, right?

Comment: In that particular example yes, but you can just tweak it to always read env.json file, which will contain the env name.