# Configuring angular production files after build

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-aot, angular-compiler, angular-cli-v9

I have an angular 9 project which is part of an application suite installer [Wix installer]. One of the settings used by the angular app is the address of API which it fetches its data from some configurable address. I know that I can have many angular environment files and simply use commands such as the followings:

```
environment.env1.ts

export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiAddress: "http://apiAddress1/api/",
};


ng build --prod --configuration=env1
```

or

```
environment.env2.ts

    export const environment = {
      production: true,
      apiAddress: "http://apiAddress2/api/",
    };

    ng build --prod --configuration=env2
```

This means for every potential API address I need to do a new build and run above command. How can I overcome above scenario and configure output binaries after the build?

Assuming there is no clear way of achieving the after-built configuration, can I do 'simple string replace' for the address of API in the generated main*.js files? Would there be any side effects?

Comment: Does that help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47938411/1160794

Answer (score 2):

You can outsource your api endpoint in a config file. And provide an `AppInitializer` to use your config file.
Here is an example:

the loader function, which loads the config via http from `/config/config.json` and sets the api configuration:

```js
export function loadConfig(http: HttpClient, config: ApiConfiguration): (() => Promise<boolean>) {
  return (): Promise<boolean> => {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve: (a: boolean) => void): void => {
      http.get('./config/config.json')
        .pipe(
          map((x: any) => {
            config.rootUrl = x.rootUrl + '/v2';
            resolve(true);
          }),
          catchError((x: { status: number }, caught: Observable<void>): ObservableInput<{}> => {
            // 404 local development, other errors are strange
            resolve(x.status === 404);
            return of({});
          })
        ).subscribe();
    });
  };
}
```

The json contains only one string named `rootUrl`.

And to use this function, before the app initializes, provide an `AppInitializer` in your `app.module.ts`:

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfig,
      deps: [
        HttpClient,
        ApiConfiguration
      ],
      multi: true
    }
```

`ApiConfiguration` stores the api endpoint which is just a class with a default value (for devlopment):

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ApiConfiguration {
  rootUrl: string = 'localhost:8080';
}
```

Just put a config file in your `/dist` folder and it should work :)

Comment: This is pretty sweet solution.  I had not heard of `APP_INITIALIZER` before.  Instead of wrapping the observable in a Promise, could you have just used `toPromise()`?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this should also work @DanielGimenez

Answer (score 1):

It is probably possible to perform a find and replace on the generated files after the build completes, but that just feels wrong.

Instead create a *configuration.json* file and put it in your assets folder.  Then in your application, reference the file directly by using an import.  You might have to enable this functionality by setting `resolveJsonModule` to `true` in your *tsconfig.json*.

Now, after the application is built, the value can be replaced in *configuration.json* without fear of unintended side effects by using simple techniques such as in NodeJs with `fs.readFileSync(path)` and `fs.writeFileSync(path, JSON.stringify(data))`.

**Sample xyz.module.ts section**

```
import dynamicConfig from '../assets/configuration.json';
@NgModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: API_BASE_URL,
      useValue: dynamicConfig.apiAddress
    }
  ]
})
export class XyzModule { }
```